# mySQL, Error 1215 - foreign key contraint

Tags: foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

My last foreign key (FK_kunde_id) in the bottom I get the following error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint. This is my secound day of SQL programming so I'm trying my best solving it, but gotten completly stuck.

* I've searched through many forums for foreign key problems. But as it's exatcly the same as FK_film_id I would assume this should work as film_id is the primary key in film.film_id

* The speeling is exactly the same.

Anyone know what creates this error from the provided code underneath:

```
create database utleie
create table utleie.kunder (
    kunde_id mediumint not null auto_increment,
    fnavn varchar(45) not null,
    enavn varchar(45) not null,
    mobil int(8) null,
    epost varchar(45) null,
    gate varchar(45) null,
    gatenr varchar(5) null,
    postnr int null,
    primary key (kunde_id) );
```

create table utleie.postnummerr (
    postnr int not null,
    poststed varchar(45) not null,
    primary key (postnr) );

create table utleie.film (
    film_id int not null auto_increment,
    tittle varchar(45) not null,
    årstall int(4) null,
    regisor varchar(45) null,
    genre varchar(3) null,
    primary key (film_id) );

create table utleie.genre (
    genre_code varchar(3) not null,
    genre varchar(45) not null,
    primary key (genre_code) );

alter table kunder add constraint FK_postnr foreign key (postnr) references postnummerr(postnr);
alter table film add constraint FK_genre foreign key (genre) references genre(genre_code);

create table utleie.utleie_oversikt (
    utleie_id int not null auto_increment,
    film_id int not null,
    kunde_id int not null,
    primary key (utleie_id) );

alter table utleie_oversikt
add constraint FK_film_id
foreign key (film_id) references film(film_id);

alter table utleie_oversikt
add constraint FK_kunde_id
foreign key (kunde_id) references kunder(kunde_id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign key references must be the exact same type. In this case, you are using mediumint and int, which are not the same size.

You'd actually need to change your create statement

```
create table utleie.utleie_oversikt (
    utleie_id int not null auto_increment,
    film_id int not null,
    kunde_id mediumint not null,
    primary key (utleie_id) );
```

or, you can change it to an int on your kinder table.